# How to stop the iterations of this code i am using the selection sort algorithm and i want the iterations to stop if the array is already sorted

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, boolean

This is my current code i place the additional foreach so i can see the iterations. i need the code to stop right after the array is already sorted what i thought of is putting a break; with a boolean if the program prints the same array twice since that would mean there is no changes already and the array is already sorted.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        int[] array = { 12, 114, 5, 10, 14 };
        foreach (int item in array) Console.Write("\t" + item);
        Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter key to start the selection...");
        Console.ReadLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int indexofSmallests = i;
            //comparison to find the smallest element in the unsorted array

            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] < array[indexofSmallests])
                 indexofSmallests = j;
            }
            //swapping part of the program
            int temp = array[i]; // temporarily storing the first element
            array[i] = array[indexofSmallests]; // copying of the smallest element
            array[indexofSmallests] = temp;

            
            foreach (int item in array) Console.Write("\t" + item);//Code so i can see the iterations

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n Sorted Array: ");// printing the final iterations
        foreach (int item in array) Console.Write("\t" + item);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What is the goal? Just for learning? Usually you would use the built-in sorting methods, and if you want a very simple sort, Insertion Sort has a better best-case performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if a sort is needed during the inner loop:

```
bool stopSort = true;

for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
{
    if (array[j] < array[indexofSmallests])
        indexofSmallests = j;
    if (array[j] < array[i])
        stopSort = false;
}

if (stopSort)
    break;
```